# Issues with getting a raspberry pi to communicate to PC with windows IOT

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi, iot

I have been having a horrible problem with trying to get this socket on the raspberry pi to correctly communicate to the PC socket. It is a TCP client-to-server setup. Both are running .net C# applications to do the communication. The main issue is not the connection, but when I send info from the raspberry pi to the computer, the computer only gets the info when I shutdown the raspberry... I believe it has to do with caching, but how would I fix this? Just a fair warning I am not well verse with sockets.

the Raspberry Pi Client Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using Windows.Web.Http;
    using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
    using Windows.Networking;
    using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
    using Windows.Storage.Streams;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace raspberrypipad
{
class TCPclient_Client
{

    private string _ip;
    private  int _port;
    private Socket _socket;
    private DataWriter _writer;
    private DataReader _reader;

    public delegate void Error(string message);
    public event Error OnError;

    public delegate void DataRecived(string data);
    public event DataRecived OnDataRecived;

    public string Ip
    {
        get { return _ip; }
        set { _ip = value; }
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get { return _port; }
        set { _port = value; }
    }

    private static ManualResetEvent _clientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    const int TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
    public async void Connect(string devicename, string pin_number, string get_portNumber, string current_ip)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Port == 0)
            {
                _port = 4444;
            }

            string result = string.Empty;

            DnsEndPoint hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(Ip, Port);
            var hostName = new HostName(Ip);
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry;

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate (object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                // Retrieve the result of this request
                result = e.SocketError.ToString();

                // Signal that the request is complete, unblocking the UI thread
                _clientDone.Set();
            });

            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Connect request over the socket
            _socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
            _socket.AcceptAsync(socketEventArg);
            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
            _socket.NoDelay = true;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ignore
        }
    }



    public string Send(string data)
    {


        string response = "Operation Timeout";

        // We are re-using the _socket object initialized in the Connect method
        if (_socket != null)
        {

            // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

            // Set properties on context object
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            socketEventArg.UserToken = null;

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order 
            // to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate (object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                e.Dispose();
                // Unblock the UI thread
                _clientDone.Set();
            });

            // Add the data to be sent into the buffer
            byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);


            // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Send request over the socket
            _socket.SendBufferSize = payload.Length;
            _socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);

            // _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

                            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        _socket.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

The server code for the computer is a little confusing, I know it works because other programs could send data to it in other languages... here is the code:

```
        public TcpServerCode(int port)
    {
        _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        _server.Start();

        _isRunning = true;

        if (!Directory.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM");


        var th = new Thread(LoopClients);
        th.Start();
    }

    public void LoopClients()
    {
        while (_isRunning)
            try
            {
                // wait for client connection
                var newClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient();


                // client found.
                // create a thread to handle communication
                var t = new Thread(HandleClient);
                var ch = new clientHolder();
                ch.generateRandomName();
                ch._tcp = newClient;
                clientHolderList.Add(ch);
                t.Start(ch);
            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {
                Log.handleException(i);
            }
    }

    public void HandleClient(object obj)
    {
        // retrieve client from parameter passed to thread
        var client = (clientHolder) obj;

        // sets two streams
        //StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client._tcp.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        var ns = client._tcp.GetStream();
        client._tcp.GetStream().ReadTimeout = 100;
        var sReader = new StreamReader(client._tcp.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

        // you could use the NetworkStream to read and write, 
        // but there is no forcing flush, even when requested

        var bClientConnected = true;
        string sData = null;

        Task getter = null;
        Task sender = null;
        while (bClientConnected)
            if (getter != null)
            {
                if (getter.IsCompleted)
                    getter = _get(sReader, client.clientName);
            }
            else
            {
                getter = _get(sReader, client.clientName);
            }
    }
    private static async Task _get(StreamReader reader, string clientName)
    {
        string sData = null;
        sData = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        reader.DiscardBufferedData();


        Console.WriteLine(sData);
        // shows content on the console.
        if (sData != null)
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt"))
                    File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt");
                File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\serverCOM\\" + clientName + "_get.txt", sData);
            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {
                Log.handleException(i);
            }
    }
```

I am assuming it is something simple to change on one of the programs, thank you in advance!

Comment: That's a bit too much to analyze for me in detail. But a general tip: Prefer the `.SendAsync` & `.ReceiveAsync` methods of `Socket` (or `.WriteAsync` and `.ReadAsync` of `NetworkStream`) of the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` based methods. The new APIs should be easier to use.

Comment: Have you check the [StreamSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) sample ?